# Can we run a Obj-C function before the app loads even though the App is based on Cordova

Tags: android, ios, web-services, cordova

We want to write Obj-C function that send at request to a web service to pass a private key and based on the response from the server we would want to continue with the execution of index.html or initiate files to be run from www folder.
Can this be done ?

Basically this means load the app under www folder / cordova only if we receive a response from the server.

Comment: If you are using Cordova, you could just do that with JS. But you also can call native functions, see [Call ObjC from JS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is pretty much possible. In AppDelegate.m file under the function didFinishLaunching which is something like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
    self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
    self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";

    // NOTE: To customize the view's frame size (which defaults to full screen), override
    // [self.viewController viewWillAppear:] in your view controller.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Put a condition to check the web services is giving the response or not at the start of the function.

Comment: Hi Rajeev, thanks for your response but ignorant of Obj-C can you please guide me how do I go about writing the condition ?

Comment: Hi Friend, you can go through the if condition of objective - c and have a fair standing about its usage.